# block some fetch requests by the service worker

Tags: service, fetch, block, progressive-web-apps, worker

I'm using SW in my PWA,
I have a fetch event, so every single request is intercepted by the SW,
i want to block in some "if cases", but it seems that the fetch event must return "event.respondWith()" synchronously.

I tried calling: event.preventDefault()
but it didnt work..

Comment: What do you mean “block”?

Comment: I want to ignore it,
so that the page won't do any redirect.

Comment: you’re case is still unclear. You can respond with whatever you want but you have to respond, why is there a link or request available if you don’t want to fill it?

Comment: I read about some cool feature called "share_target", in it's V2 there  is an option to share files from android gallery directly to the PWA.
the way it's implemented is by sending a "POST" request from the gallery to the SW, and the fetch event should catch it and resond to it.
in every implementation I read, they always redirect the page so that it won't redirect to it's actual location.

In my PWA i'm using a single dynamic page which never refresh unless it's reopen.
I want to be able to recive that post message from the "share_target" as I already did, and ignore the default redirect

Comment: Oh you just need to respond with the share target then I think, you can respond with anything you like in the sw

Comment: I'm helpless, I tried everything, it seems that it has to redirect explicitly in order to override the share target redirection.. that's why I wanted to ignore that redirection some how, just like preventdefault() in js events

Comment: I don't want to respond so that the page won't refresh

Comment: Ah, I thought you meant a JS based fetch request. You can’t block a request with an SW something has to resolve. If you want to block page clicks it has to happen before fetch is triggered